# Google Code shows my email some.thing@gmail.com, where can I change this?

Tags: username, google-code

I've been using Google Code as a regular User (not developer!) for some time, e.g. creating or commenting on issues.

However it always bothered me that it always shows my full email to me there: `some.thing@gmail.com` . I'd really prefer to have been shown a short name, e.g. my first name or something. For example, when I join a Google Group I can specify a name for it.

Where can I change this for Google Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as of now, there is an [open ticket](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=60) on the same.